# find all spring @value properties

Tags: java, spring

I would like to get a list of the properties configured in my system using the @Value annotation from spring. Is it possible? I need the configuration key that is set in the @Value().

I know I can scan for annotations, but is there a better way to do this? If perhaps there is some support in the spring framework to get this information.

Comment: Take a look at ["Reflection"](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)

Comment: Thanks, I did considered this but hoped it was a better way of doing it, if perhaps spring had support for it somehow.

Comment: If you only want the values that are used in the app and not all the values that are available in properties files (or command line), you'll have to cope with reflection (from scratch or with Reflection tool or Spring itself).

Comment: @Jarle Spring has a class `AnnotationUtils` that *might* help you here.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is the main reason why scattering `@Value` all over your code is a bad idea.

You should instead create some kind of central "configuration service" in your application, and let that be the single point of contact for your configuration values. In there, you can have all the `@Value` fields you want.

Then, you `@Autowire` your configuration service instead, and the classes can ask it for the necessary stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This is all fine and good (and we actually do this), but I still want to generate some sort of documentation automatically that displays the configuration options for all types of services.

Comment: @Jarle Would putting Javadoc on the various fields and methods in the configuration service not serve this purpose?

Comment: That is certainly an option. It still feels like a somewhat manual process to me, would like something that works without the service developer needing to do anything.